# What should I do if AF isn't working on my lens after sending it to Sigma for a different repair?

Tags: repair, sigma

I have bought a Sigma lens for my Canon 600D. Since the beginning the photos were slightly blurred and lacked sharpness, independently of the aperture. So I sent it to Sigma for service. When I got the lens back the AF was not working. Now there is no way to focus. Don't know what to do anymore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is an 18-250mm zoom lens. That's a focal length ratio of 13.89X. Why would you expect such a lens to not be slightly blurry and lack sharpness?

Answer (score 3):

If you are certain the issue is not user error, and have tried the lens on another working camera body, you need to call the service center and discuss your concerns with them.